# Buying/Selling Stock algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

Although I am fine with any other programming languages, Try to give ideas/answers in PHP

There's an array that has the following pattern;

```
$arr = array(
   0 => '12',
   1 => '38',
   2 => '25',
   3 => '4',
   ...
   365 => '45',
);
```

It is basically an array of values and stock prices for the full year, 365 days.

`As far as I can remember the question;`

- As `$arr` as your input, write a function, so you can buy a stock when it is low and sell when it is high. Function must return the following array

  ```
  $return = array(
      'buy-date'  => '', // day you should've bought, so it price should be low
      'sell-date' => '', // day you should've sold, so its price should be high so you make profit
      'profit'    => ''  // value of profit
  );
  ```
- Important note; You can't sell more than 30 days after you bought a stock.

So the trick is for any given time period/month maybe you want to buy on the lowest date but since you can't sell after 30 days you buying the stock you may want to buy on the 4th lowest day so you still can sell within the next best selling day. (hope I was clear on this)

Aside from given me code snippets, give me ideas, algorithms etc, I would like to understand how to approach to a question like this.

Comment: want maximum profit? if not, it's little bit easier.  try to use asort to sort the array and compare lowest index (key) and highest index for 30 days

Answer (score 3):

The brute-force approach is easy to code. For each day 0-335, calculate the profit if you buy on that day and sell in the next 1-30 days. If profit is greater than max profit found so far, remember it as max profit, along with buy and sell date.

Comment: I thought that was the most obvious part: profit is the difference between the buy and sell price.